# Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I am getting the below exception while running SQL queries from **PHP** (Version 5.4.42). I am using PDO to connect  **SQL SERVER**.

```
Exception while query the database; Error: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: mixed named and positional parameters
```

**CODE**

```
<?php
$query = 'SOME SQL QUERY';
$db = new PDO('odbc:Driver={SQL Server};Server=$SERVER;Database=$DATABASE; Uid=sa;Pwd=*****;', null, null,array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT => true)); 
$stmt = $db->query($query);
$result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>
```

**I am not using any positional parameter. No Prepare or Bind.**

My Query

```
UPDATE TABLE SET COLUMN = VALUE
```

Scenario where is working fine.

- If VALUE string length is Big (tens of thousand character) without special character.
- If VALUE string length is small (some thousands character) with
  Special character(#$%?*&:<>{}).

Scenario where the query is failing.

- VALUE string contains tens of thousand character with some special
  characters(#$%?*&:<>{}).

If VALUE sting contains hundreds of thousands of alphabetic character then it works fine. Now add one question mark character and query will fail. But insert thousands of 'question marks' character and query will work fine. This look wired but this what I able to conclude after Trial and error Method.

**NOTE** If I run any kind of query from SQL Server Management Studio. It works fine.

Comment: Can you provide a sample query that fails?

Comment: UPDATE Tasks SET notes = $VALUE
Now take any random character string with length about 90000+ character.

Comment: What happen when you do this: `echo $stmt->queryString;`

Comment: It prints the query.. and that query works fine in Sql Server Management Studio.

Comment: Before down vote at least, let the user know the issue?? question is very specific.. read the question... I have give error name.. then gave the details.. then gave trial and error method based observations.. what else someone need??